# changing url dynamically in angular 4 depending upon the environments

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-router

right now to change the url for angular 4 application i am using ng build--(name of the flag)
for example if it is production i use ng build --prod

what i want to achieve is for example-
for  local host if the URL is -https://local.com/application/overview

for  staging  it is - for my local host if the URL is -https://stage.com/application/overview

for  production the url is it is - for my local host if the URL is -https://prod.com/application/overview.

i want to to change the hostname dynamically with me changing the url again and again. if the code is deployed to stage it should take the stage url and vice versa.

how it can be achieved? any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your context root after first / is same in every environment then you don't need to provide a base href just use ./

Comment: i didn't get what are you trying to say.

Comment: Where you are deploying this application Apache webserver or tomcat

Comment: apache webserver

Comment: It must not be issue you should only add base href as your ./index.html# and from Apache static web server make a context mapping for that static file i.e index.html file in your Apache mod rule for context rule mapping